# what is the main difference between android.animation and android.transition package?

Tags: android, animation

We can create animations using both android.animation package and android.transition package but I would like to know what is the main difference between these packages since even custom transitions also use animator's from android animation package.

Answer (score 5):

From the documentation of **`android.animation`**:

> These classes provide functionality for the **property animation** system,
>   which allows you to **animate object properties** of any type.

From the documentation of **`android.transition`**:

> The classes in this package enable "**scenes & transitions**" functionality **for view hiearchies**.

From there a conclusion could be made that `android.animation` mostly handles individual View animation (a FAB moving left upon click, etc) while `android.transition` cares mostly about view hierarchy/layout transition animation (Material Design shared elements, etc).

Comment: so can I draw a conclusion that transition is a level above animation.

Comment: Not exactly above, but it does intended to serve bigger scope of `View`s (plural); rather than the individuals intended by `android.animation`.

Answer (score 0):

do read about fundamental difference at http://developer.android.com/about/versions/android-4.4.html in 'Animation & Graphics' section. 
Basically, you can transition between different states of UI by defining Scene objects.
I don't have any code to support as i haven't used this till now, but above link should get you started.